# Docker container DNS problem. Letsencrypt ghcr.io/linuxserver/swag

Tags: docker, networking, dns, lets-encrypt

Good morning, I am having a DNS problem within a Docker container. It does not resolve any name, but it does resolve all IP's. You can reproduce the problem by executing (changing URL=MY_URL):

```
docker run -d --name=swag5 --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -e PUID=1000 -e PGID=1000 -e TZ=Europe/London -e URL=MY_URL -e SUBDOMAINS=www, -e VALIDATION=http -p 443:443 -v /root/letsencrypt/templates:/config --restart unless-stopped ghcr.io/linuxserver/swag --add-host="acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:104.99.248.78" -e STAGING=true -e EMAIL=MY_EMAIL@MY_COMPANY.onmicrosoft.com -e DNSPLUGIN=digitalocean
```

The host perfectly solves the machine "acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org".

Things I have tried:

I have tried changing the DNS in the host's daemon.json and it still doesn't work

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json     (before 8.8.8.8)
{
    "dns": ["169.53.182.120 "," 176.9.1.117","194.224.52.37","8.8.8.8"]
}
```

I have tried to manually add the host in the run:
-add-host = "acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org:104.99.248.78"

I have tried adding port 53 (DNS, Domain Name System) to the firewall.

I also temporarily disabled fw.

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere
2375/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
2376/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
25060                      ALLOW       Anywhere
53                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
2375/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2376/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25060 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
53 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

80/tcp                     ALLOW FWD   Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

I have tried to put the option DNSPLUGIN = digitalocean: the machine is in digitalocean (provider of machines in the cloud)

/etc/resolv.conf (container, originally only->8.8.8.8)

```
    nameserver 169.53.182.120
nameserver  176.9.1.117
nameserver 194.224.52.37
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ip addr (Host-Ubuntu 20)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:0e:fc:97:57:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet XXX.XX.XXX.XX/20 brd XXX.XX.XXX.XXX scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.19.0.7/16 brd 10.19.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 XXX::280e:XXXX:fe97:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:e0:5c:d4:XX:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.XXX.0.9/20 brd 10.XXX.15.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:5cff:fed4:81f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:XX:f6:3e:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:3fff:fef6:3ebb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip addr (container)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
35: eth0@if36: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

root@f63f87fb8f:/# nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

any ideas? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I did not have the outgoing UDP port 53 open on the firewall.

Thank you all!